# role acl issues when applying to user

Tags: role, access

I have inventory module which is a grid and is showing in admin panel 
this module is under catalog tab I created role inventory and this role should see just the module
in etc folder config.xml I wrote the acl as follow:

```
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <catalog>
        <children>
                <inventory>
                    <title>Inventory</title>
                           <children>
                                <inventory translate="inventory" module="inventory">
                                    <title>Lenmar US</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </inventory>

                            </children>

                </inventory>
                </children>
                </catalog></children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

more over in controller I have this for allow:

```
    class Lenmar_Inventory_Adminhtml_InventoryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
    {
    protected function _isAllowed()
        {
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('inventory/inventory');
        }       
//continued
```

in role resources I can see that the inventory  is under the catalog and when I choose the inventory the catalog will be chosen
but I have access denied when going to user with that role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

`return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/inventory/inventory');`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough! you're the Best! a real expert:)